# Infinitspan problem after moving from Wildfly 8.2 to WildFly11

Tags: java, migration, wildfly-8, java-ee-8, wildfly-11

I want to move my project from Wildfly 8.2 into newer version (i.e ver 11). 
Of course on WF8.2 everything works ok.
After using jboss-migration-tool and trying deploy package on newer version I got everytime:

> 12:55:36,838 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
>   (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
>   address: ([("deployment" => "my-app.war")]) - failure
>   description: {
>       "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.infinispan.container.myapp"],
>       "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>           "jboss.naming.context.java.module.myapp-core.myapp.env.\"com.myapp.core.midware.server.services.ws.services.SingletonEJB\"._embeddedCacheContainer
>   is missing ] }

I don't know what to do. I tried to move infinitspan from 8.2 (version 6.0.2-Final) but entire WF application wont start. Now I update pom.xml to get newer version of that (8.2.8-Final), made package, but still it shows up.

Even i tried to comment from file (com.myapp.core.midware.server.services.ws.services.SingletonEJB):

```
//  @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/nmarket")
//  private CacheContainer _embeddedCacheContainer;
```

and assigned against it new DefaultCacheManager to reference:

```
_cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager();   //_embeddedCacheContainer.getCache().getCacheManager();
```

it shows up.

Thank you for your help

EDIT:

This is section for infinitspan in standalone-full.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:4.0">
        <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="concurrent">
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="ejb" aliases="sfsb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="passivation">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="persistent">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate.infinispan">
            <local-cache name="entity">
                <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="local-query">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
            </local-cache>
            <local-cache name="timestamps">
                <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
        <cache-container name="server" default-cache="default" module="org.wildfly.clustering.server">
            <local-cache name="default">
                <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
    </subsystem>
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters I'd start with a more recent version. The latest release is currently  WildFly 19.1.0. (https://wildfly.org/news/2020/05/04/WildFly-1910-Released/). I upgrade WildFly every time it's released.

I also switched to Gradle (now 6.3) when I upgraded to WildFly 12 in ~2017. IMO It's a lot easier than Maven creating JARs and deploying (JAR + WAR) your EAR.